# postinst script doesn't run after installation

Tags: debian, debian-installer, deb

I have a folder with the following folder structure:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 mar 21 19:08 DEBIAN
drwxr-xr-x 6 pi pi 4096 mar 21 18:02 usr
```

Inside `DEBIAN` folder:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   150 mar 21 18:05 changelog
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi     2 mar 21 18:05 compat
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   516 mar 21 18:05 control
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 13774 mar 21 18:05 copyright
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  1396 mar 21 20:45 postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi   919 mar 21 19:08 postrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi   679 mar 21 19:08 preinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi   866 mar 21 19:08 prerm
```

The `postinst` file is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# postinst script for cpython
#
# see: dh_installdeb(1)

set -e

# summary of how this script can be called:
#        * <postinst> `configure' <most-recently-configured-version>
#        * <old-postinst> `abort-upgrade' <new version>
#        * <conflictor's-postinst> `abort-remove' `in-favour' <package>
#          <new-version>
#        * <postinst> `abort-remove'
#        * <deconfigured's-postinst> `abort-deconfigure' `in-favour'
#          <failed-install-package> <version> `removing'
#          <conflicting-package> <version>
# for details, see http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ or
# the debian-policy package


case "$1" in
    configure)
    ;;

    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;

    *)

        #echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        #exit 1
    ;;
esac

ln -sf XXX YYY

# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.


exit 0
```

The scripts were copied into that folder with `dh_installdeb` command from `package.postinst`, `package.postrm`, `package.preinst`, `package.prerm`. (these files were genereated with `dh_make -f` command).

When I run `fakeroot dpkg-deb --build python3.6` to create the `.deb` it creates the `.deb`, but when I try to install it it doesn't run `postinst` (it doesn't create the symbolic link that appears in the script).

One strange thing is that in the `DEBIAN` folder, the script contains the following:

```sh
# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.
```

If I extract the content of generated `.deb` and inspect the `postinst` file, I observer the same message:

```sh
# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.
```

That line makes me think that I am forgetting something or doing something wrong.

Why doesn't my `postinst` script run after `sudo dpkg -i xxx.deb` command?

Comment: I take it you're not using `debian/rules` and `dpkg-buildpackage` to build your package(s), is that correct? If so, why not? There's no need to fiddle with `dh_installdeb` and `dpkg-deb` directly.

Comment: The first time that I created the package I used `dpkg-buildpackage` and `debian/rules` But know I am doing it manually because with `dphk--buildpackage` I can't (or I don't know) how to generated `.deb` again without compiling the whole program.

Comment: I have used `dpkg-buildpackage` to create the package again, with a `postinst.ex` script and the package and I figure out that `postinst` script doesn't run even generating the package with `dpkg-buildpackage` and moreover if I unpack the deb generated, the `postinst` script show `# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.` again!

Comment: I'm assuming you renamed your `postinst.ex` appropriately. Without seeing all your packaging I don't know what might need fixing, but I recommend just using the [existing Python 3.6 packaging](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python3.6) and rebuilding that for your system.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to simply install the symlink?  If its name and target are constant, then just install it normally.  Consider also the "alternatives" mechanism if you're providing a choice of implementations.  Only create a symlink in `postinst` as a last resort (and remember to clean it up on uninstall or purge).